# Looking for a flash uploader to upload large files

Tags: php, flash, upload, large-files

I need a flash uploader, to use it in my CMS project.

I need something like [this](http://www.solmetra.com/en/disp.php/en_products/flash_uploader/uploader_intro), but with greater max upload size (it doesn't allow to upload files larger `ini_get('upload_max_filesize')`).

My server doesn't allow me to overwrite ini settings, so I'm looking for an uploader which can upload large files independently from the ini settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go around the ini limit, one option would be to change and use an FTP uploader.

I've used once [**net2ftp**](http://www.net2ftp.com/) and it was easy enough in its installation; I've never used it again since (almost 1 year and a half), but I see from their page that the project is updated and not dead, so you might give it a try. 
You just download the package, place it in your webapp, customize it, and you're set.

You might want to create a dedicated FTP user with appropriate permissions, and not use the *root* one, of course.

Comment: Interesting idea. But i heard somewhere, then there are some scripts, which automatically splits large files and upload them part by part to server. Is it real, or that from fantastic genre? :)

Comment: Well, that can be a solution, but I know nothing about that...but still you would need to break the huge file _before_ sending, so you need some local tool (Java?) that, if file is larger than allowed by your php.ini, splits it and then uploads each piece one after the other. So...why not ftp?

Answer (score 0):

You wont be able to post more data to the server than the max_upload_size.

As a workaround you can upload the data to [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and sync it back via [s3sync](http://s3sync.net/wiki).
We have a setup with [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) in place for one of our clients and are able to upload up to 2GB per file (that's a client restriction, I don't know about S3 restrictions)

Mind you that S3 costs some money.